# Strange behavior in Laravel 7.2 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, laravel-formrequest

I have a project with a fairly standard Dev-on-Homestead to Staging to Production workflow.  All are using Laravel 7.2.2/Ubuntu 18.04/PHP 7.4.3

This cropped up today with some form requests.

```
Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError
Type of App\Http\Requests\CreateHighlight::$errorBag must be string (as in class Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest)
```

This is a named `$errorBag` that we've been using since 5.4 or so?

I changed the $errorBag to `protected string $errorBag='highlightCreate';` and proceeded to test and deploy.

That same code kicked this back from the staging error logs:

```
staging.ERROR: Type of App\Http\Requests\CreateHighlight::$errorBag must not be defined (as in class Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest)
```

I have checked and rechecked and checked a fourth, fifth, sixth time. Everything appears to be identical between the two environments, yet I cannot for the life of me understand why this is happening. They're the same error except they're contradicting each other.

Comment: Based on https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/2f20a5d6eb1c3047ae23e81fa07c74d2573cbf4b/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.php#L59 it clearly seems like errorbag is not defined as a string. Can you give more info that can point us in the right direction?

Comment: As I've said, I've checked everything. I've seen line 59 of FormRequest.php; it's the same in both versions. I don't know why one is throwing an error if it's not declared explicitly as a string and the other throws an error if it is.  It seems ridiculous.

Comment: Looking at the commit history for FormRequest.php makes things even weirder--there's no commit I can find that has that in it, so I must've introduced the error myself. But I don't even know how that's possible. I've never even opened the ```vendor``` folder for this project before today.

Comment: @mrhn, I apparently edited out my comment. It was the line 59 in FormRequest.php. Somehow it had gotten changed to ```protected string $errorBag...``` on my local installation.  As I said above, that must've been me, though I don't know how I did it. Thank you for suggesting I look some more. If you want to write a solution, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [FormRequest](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/2f20a5d6eb1c3047ae23e81fa07c74d2573cbf4b/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.php#L59) it clearly seems like `errorBag` is not defined as a string. This clearly seems like it is something with your local file there is wrong. Never the less the `errorBag` should not be defined as a string.